# Swift: Best way to get value from view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom UIView (called GridView) that I initialize and then add to a ViewController (DetailViewController). GridView contains several UIButtons and I would like to know in DetailViewController when those buttons are touched. I'm new to Swift and am wondering what is the best pattern to use to get those events?

Comment: It seems like NSNotificationCenter would be one way. Any specific tips on how to implement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with notifications, use [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotification:):

```
func postNotificationName(_ notificationName: String,
    object notificationSender: AnyObject?)
```

in the method that is triggered by your button. Then, in your `DetailViewController`, add a listener when it is initialized with [2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:):

```
func addObserver(_ notificationObserver: AnyObject,
    selector notificationSelector: Selector,
        name notificationName: String?,
      object notificationSender: AnyObject?)
```

Both functions can be called from `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()`.

Another method would be to add callbacks which you connect once you initialize the `GridView` in your `DetailViewController`. A callback is essentially a closure:

```
var callback : (() -> Void)?
```

which you can instantiate when needed, e.g.

```
// In DetailViewController initialization
gridView = GridView()
gridView.callback = { self.doSomething() }
```

In `GridView` you can trigger the callback like this:

```
func onButton()
{
    callback?()
}
```

The callback will only execute, if unwrapping succeeds. Please ensure, that you have read [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), because these constructs may lead to strong reference cycles.

What's the difference? You can connect the callback only once (at least with the method I've showed here), but when it triggers, the receiver immediately executes its code. For notifications, you can have multiple receivers but there is some delay in event delivery.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about callbacks. Both seem like viable options.

Comment: What you could also do is make a `delegate`, if you have many buttons which all have a meaning, this might be more useful than connecting a lot of callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your GridView implementation is like as follows:

```
class GridView : UIView {
    // Initializing buttons
    let button1:UIButton = UIButton(...)
    let button2:UIButton = UIButton(...)
    // ...

    // Adding buttons to view
    self.addSubview(button1)
    self.addSubview(button2)
    // ... 
}
```

Now, we will add selector methods which will be called when a button is touched. Lets assume implementation of your view controller is like as follows:

```
class DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    let myView:GridView = GridView(...)

    myView.button1.addTarget(self, action: "actionForButton1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    myView.button2.addTarget(self, action: "actionForButton2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    // ...

    func actionForButton1(sender: UIButton!) {
        // Your actions when button 1 is pressed
    }
    // ... Selectors for other buttons
}
```

I have to say that my example approach is **not** a good example for encapsulation principles of Object-Oriented Programming, but I have written like this because you are new to Swift and this code is easy to understand. If you want to prevent duplicate codes such as writing different selectors for each button and if you want to set properties of your view as private to prevent access from "outside" like I just did in DetailViewController, there are much much better solutions. I hope it just helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you better create a class called `GridView` that is inherited from the `UIView`. Then, you can connect all you UI element with you class as `IBOutlet` or whatever using tag something like that. Later on, you can ask the instance of `GridView` in `DetailViewController` so that you can connect as `IBAction`.

**Encapsulation** is one of the principles of OOP.